# Browser tab not showing full URL?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a odd issue with this site I'm building:

http://limetreeyoga.uk

If you click on "about" it takes you to the "about" page but if you refresh the page it takes you back to the home page?

Same with the other pages, its also not showing the "title" tag in the browser? I have no idea why, can anyone help?

Cheers
T

Answer (score 2):

This website uses FRAMES - extremely old (i.e. outdated) technology....

The outer frame always stays the same, that's the reason for the reload problem. Only the inner frames change when you click the menu.

ADDITION: In fact, it seems you have a complete regular (useable) document structure *inside*  the first frame. Try to erase all HTML outside the first `<frame>` element - that might even work... (although I didn't look into it in detail)

Comment: The page links to the iframe. You should copy the info on that page and make a new page called about.html. EDIT Your entire website is using iframe to the old site, Get rid of that and make a Home index.html, about.html, yogaclasses.html and contact.html pages.

Comment: @mlegg there is no iframe. There is a frameset with ("regular") frames inside it, where only the first one contains the complete page.

Comment: I know but that's old code, not supported in html5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp